# casting an object array java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I declared an array of objects. Is it possible to use my custom Node class instead of a generic object array ? Here is my code:

```
Object[] pos = new Object[28];
pos[1] = new HashSet<String>();
```

My node class contains only string values. I tried doing it directly but it doesn't work.

```
Node[] pos = new Node[28];
pos[1] = new HashSet<String>();
```

Comment: Why don't you use a map instead of node array?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: try `pos1 = new Node();`

Comment: `pos` is supposedly an array of Node.  But you're attempting to assign a HashSet to it's element 1.  You'd get essentially the same error if you attempted to assign to a simple var of class Node.

Comment: Read up on the subclass/superclass thing, and all the implications thereby.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're even trying to do.  Why do you want an array of HashSet?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do what you did: when you declare an array of type `Node`, only objects of type `Node` or types *derived* from it through inheritance can be array elements.

The reason this works with `Object[]` array is that `Object` is the base class of every Java object. `HashSet<String>` objects can be converted to type `java.lang.Object`, but they cannot be converted to an unrelated type `Node`.

Comment: is there any workaround ?

Comment: No.  Why do you want to work-around it?

Comment: @user2326847 - Learn about class inheritance.

Comment: @user2326847 You need to pick a type that is a base of the `HashSet<String>` (i.e. `Object`, `Collection`, or `AbstractSet`) or one of its interfaces (i.e. `Serializable`, `Cloneable`, `Iterable`, `Collection`, or `Set`). See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) for the list of base types (see the hierarchy at the top)

Answer (score 1):

```
  Object[] pos = new Object[28];
  pos[1] = new HashSet<String>();
```

This works because a HashSet **is an Object**.

```
 Node[] pos = new Node[28];
 pos[1] = new HashSet<String>();
```

This **does not work** because **A Node is not a HashSet**. You can not put a HashSet in an array where Nodes are expected.

Answer (score 0):

here try this one:

```
String[] stringArray = (String[])valid.toArray(new String[valid.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well  when you do

```
Node[] pos = new Node[28];
```

it means you are telling to compiler that you are creating the array of Node Object whose length is 28. But when you do below

```
  pos[1] = new HashSet<String>();
```

You are trying to store HashSet Object instead of your node object. Thats the sompilation issue issue.

But with Object array it will work as Object is the super class of every other class in java